# Event Handler for onSelect in InfiniteCalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, events, event-handling

I'm trying to get the `selected` date value in [`InfiniteCalendar`](https://github.com/clauderic/react-infinite-calendar/blob/master/README.md#basic-example) of React framework, could not make it work yet. How do I do that?

My desired output is to display the date in the data preview in the following demo:

#### [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-fast-iz550)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InfiniteCalendar from 'react-infinite-calendar';
import 'react-infinite-calendar/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

// Render the Calendar
var today = new Date();
var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);

render(
  <InfiniteCalendar
    width={400}
    height={600}
    selected={today}
    disabledDays={[0,6]}
    minDate={lastWeek}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Thanks! I'm new to React.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the selected value, you need to made a function to manage this value, and pass this function as argument in the `onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}` of the InfiniteCalendar Component.

PD. I deleted elements just to keep more little the example.

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import { Form, Field } from "react-advanced-form";
import { Input, Button, Checkbox } from "react-advanced-form-addons";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
import InfiniteCalendar from "react-infinite-calendar";
import "react-infinite-calendar/styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

  handleOnSelect = selectedDate => {
    console.log(selectedDate);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="container">
        <Form onSubmitStart={this.props.onSubmitStart}>
          <p>Date of Birth</p>
          <InfiniteCalendar
            name="dateOfBirth1"
            onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}
          />
        </Form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see more about the problem, and I don't know how to resolve it, but one thing I see is that you need to find how to set the value of custom components in your react-advamced-form schema, because the phone number input neither is set in the previsualization component (for the same reason).